# Is it possible to efficiently measure outer products of quantum states, of the form $|a\rangle\langle b|$?

Tags: quantum-state, information-theory, linear-algebra, state-tomography, nisq

I am looking at a matrix reconstruction algorithm that, given singular values $\sigma_i$ and quantum states $|u_i\rangle$ and $|v_i\rangle$ that are efficiently prepared on a quantum computer, produces a matrix $M$ such that

$M=\sum_i \sigma_i |u_i \rangle\langle v_i|$.

It seems like I can do two things:

I) Quantum State Tomography on both $|u_i\rangle$ and $|v_i\rangle$, and then classically reconstructing the outer product. This seems to take an exponential number of measurements because of the output problem. There exists https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.11071 which says that you can measure $|u_i\rangle$ and $|v_i\rangle$ with a number of bases that is linear in the number of qubits.

II) Since $|u_i\rangle\langle v_i|$ is rank-1, there might exist an efficient way to reconstruct it altogether, though I haven't seen any literature that supports an efficient algorithm for doing this.

Are there any clues that support efficient reconstruction here? Please note that the vectors $|u_i\rangle$ and $|v_i\rangle$ have real entries only.

Answer (score 3):

This outer product is, in general, not Hermitian and so does not correspond directly to a physical observable. Taking a lesson from $2\times 2$ matrices (ie from polarimetry), we can measure the two Hermitian observables
$$X=|a\rangle\langle b|+|b\rangle\langle a|$$ and $$Y=-i(|a\rangle\langle b|-|b\rangle\langle a|),$$ then use post-processing to say that the expectation values should satisfy
$$\big\langle |a\rangle \langle b|\big\rangle=\big\langle X\big\rangle+i\big\langle Y\big\rangle.$$

Comment: Interesting idea, thank you! How'd you go around constructing those observables if you do not know $|a\rangle$ and $|b\rangle$, but you do know how to efficiently prepare them?

Comment: @JoJo if you can efficiently prepare a superposition of the two then you're good: the superpositions $|a\rangle\pm|b\rangle$ are the eigenstates of my $X$ and the superpositions $|a\rangle\pm i|b\rangle$ are the eigenstates of my $Y$, so projecting onto those states would be an efficient way to measure $X$ and then $Y$

Answer (score 1):

If you know $|u_i\rangle\langle v_i|$ then you can deduce $|u_i\rangle$ and $|v_i\rangle$ as well (up to a global phase). So, reconstructing the product can't be easier then reconstruction of the states.

But since $|u_i\rangle$, $|v_i\rangle$ are real it's enough to use measurements in the standard basis to reconstruct them.